# Stored procedure multiplying values from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am stuck with a stored procedure.

I have these 2 tables in a database:

Transaction

| tID | cID | carID | eID | tDate | PickupDate | ReturnDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 1006 | 1004 | 104 | 2018-04-18 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-2 |

Car

| CarID | Make | Model | Type | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | Ford | Focus | Hatch | 2019 | 140.00 |

I need to calculate what 10% of a transaction cost is for tax purposes. I have managed to get the length of the rental and stored it into a variable, but can't figure out how I can get the price of the car used in the transaction to then multiple the length by the price and then display the result.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Tax_Due
    @tID INT
AS
    DECLARE @carPrice as INT
    DECLARE @rentLength as INT

    SELECT  @rentLength = DATEDIFF(day, PickupDate, ReturnDate) 
    FROM [Transaction]
    WHERE tID = @tID

    SELECT @carPrice = Price  
    FROM Car
    WHERE
```

Comment: Your code is not MySQL code.  What database are you really using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: The question cannot be multiplying values from different tables, because you already have the "@rentength" into a variable. It doesn't matter to this problem, where it comes from. 
Also, it is very unlikely to return the car before he/she picked it up. Please redefine your question and tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why you can't just join the tables and do a calculation like this

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, PickupDate, ReturnDate) * Price.Price * .1 as tax
FROM    [Transaction] join [Price] on Transaction.carID = Price.carID
WHERE   tID = @tID
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. It worked, just changed a few names.